# Issue installing mysql-server-5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, mysqli, lamp

I am getting this error message when I try to install `mysql-server-5.6: sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.6
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/6,004 kB of archives.
After this operation, 52.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 75769 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.6_5.6.35-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+0.1_amd64.deb ...
Aborting downgrade from (at least) 5.7 to 5.6.
If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.6, remove the file
/var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.6_5.6.35-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+0.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.6_5.6.35-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+0.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`mysql-client-5.6` were installed normally.

I first, uninstalled `mysql-server-5.7`:

```
sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

I added repos using this 2 methods:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe'
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.6
sudo apt-get update
```

Notice that I also installed `PHP 5.6` without any problem.

Since all my project depend on `MCRYPT`, I have to install this version in order to it to works well.

I used `mysql-server-5.7` but it is not compatible ... datas are not inserted into mysql server.

Your help is needed, thank you in advance.

Comment: It says in the error message: `If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.6, remove the file /var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.` -- did you try removing that file?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the mysql client, because you already have it and it is trying to install it, which is causing the error.

Run this command to cleanup unused libraries:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then try to install it again

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer but I already did, you can check my post :)